# Unable to get yt channel name using xpath node with Selenium/testNG

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium, testng

My task is to open browser, go to YT, enter search term "qtp", click on Search button. On the results page, I want to get the Channel Name. To accomplish this, I used Firebug application to get the following path for 1st 3 channel names:

When I execute the following code using Selenium / testNG, I catch the exception, which states, "Element not found".
I tried the similar code with Selenium only (without TestNG) and still didn't work. Tried with WebDriver, still didn't work.

I do understand that it could some issue with the node, but I am unable to figure it out.

Jars Used:
selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar,junit-4.10.jar,selenium-java-2.35.0.jar,selenium-server-2.35.0.jar;

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException;


public class YT1 extends SeleneseTestCase{
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(){
System.out.println("Before");
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,"*firefox","http://www.youtube.com"); 
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Test");
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.type("//*[@id='masthead-search-term']", "qtp");
    selenium.click("//*[@id='search-btn']");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    try {
    System.out.println(selenium.getText("//html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ol/li[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
    }
    catch (SeleniumException se1){
        System.out.println("Element not Found because: " + se1);
    }
    try {
    System.out.println(selenium.getText("//html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ol/li[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
        }
        catch (SeleniumException se2){
            System.out.println("Element not Found because: " + se2);
        }
    try {
        System.out.println(selenium.getText("//html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ol/li[3]/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
        }
        catch (SeleniumException se3){
            System.out.println("Element not Found because: " + se3);
    }
}
@AfterTest
public void ShutDown(){
    System.out.println("After Test");
    selenium.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What "channel name" are you referring to? In result pages in my browser I see a list of results, with a title and a author (among other things on YouTube pages)

Comment: Channel name is the name of the person/company/author who has uploaded the video, in my search for qtp, the first three results for author names shows as as by Karthik elearn, where "Karthik elearn" is the location, whose text I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following XPath expression:

```
.//div[@id="results"]
    /ol[@id="search-results"]/li
        /div[contains(@class, "yt-lockup-content")]
            /div[contains(@class, "yt-lockup-meta")]
                //a[contains(@class, "yt-user-name")]
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul t., I am a newbie at this .. hence I am afraid I dont know the implementation of your code.. however, I was trying different things during that time. I was successful with the following code:        System.out.println(selenium.getText("//*[@id='search-results']/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));                     I was able to extract this info from Chrome Browser. This works!!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @pault's solution would be to use CSS. [It's cleaner, quicker, and more readable.](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)

```
div#results > ol#search-results > li > div.yt-lookup-content > div.yt-lookup-meta a.yt-user-name
```

Comment: Definitely! I don't use Selenium at all so I wasn't sure if CSS selectors were an option

Comment: I will definitely invest my time in learning this. Thanks for sharing the video